# specifying component layout in a dash app

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python, dash-bootstrap-components

I am trying to format the components of a dash app using [dash bootstrap components](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/).  I would like to have the graph in the image next to a slider component, as indicated in the bottom image.
It's not working as expected – please could someone indicate what (probably basic) mistake I am making?

Many thanks!

**CODE:**

```
app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Tabs(id = 'user_tabs',
                                value = 'dynamic_score',
                                vertical = True,
                                children = [dcc.Tab(label = metric[0].upper() + ''.join(i.lower() for i in metric[1:]), 
                                                    value = metric,
                                                    children=[html.H4('Live adjustable graph-size'),
                                                              html.P("Change figure width:"),
                                                              #https://stackoverflow.com/a/60491495/11357695
                                                              dbc.Container(children = [dbc.Row(dbc.Col(html.Div([dcc.Slider(id=f'{metric}_slider_width', 
                                                                                                                             min=100, 
                                                                                                                             max=2000, 
                                                                                                                             step=100, 
                                                                                                                             value=2000,
                                                                                                                             marks={x: str(x) for x in range(100, 2000, 100)})],
                                                                                                                             style = {'width': '50%'}))),
                                                                                         dbc.Row([dbc.Col(dcc.Slider(id=f'{metric}_slider_height',  
                                                                                                                     min=100, 
                                                                                                                     max=2000, 
                                                                                                                     step=100, 
                                                                                                                     value=1000,
                                                                                                                     marks={x: str(x) for x in range(100, 2000, 100)},
                                                                                                                     vertical = True),
                                                                                                          align = 'start'),
                                                                                                  dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id=f'{metric}_graph'),
                                                                                                          align = 'center')
                                                                                                  ])
                                                                                         ]),
                
                                                              html.Div([html.H4('max val', 
                                                                                style= {'display':'inline-block',
                                                                                        'margin-right':20, 
                                                                                        'margin-top':0}),
                                                                        dcc.Input(id=f'{metric}_max_val',
                                                                                  type='number',
                                                                                  value = 1000000, 
                                                                                  style={'display':'inline-block'})], 
                                                                        style={'display':'inline-block', 
                                                                                'width': '100%'}) 
                                                              ]) for metric, val in my_vals] + 
                                
                                    #included for complete code, but am waiting to get a working bootstrap implementation before including in the layoutr below
                                    [dcc.Tab(label='dynamic_score', 
                                             value = 'dynamic_score',
                                             
                                             children = [html.H4('Live adjustable graph-size'),
                                                            html.P("Change figure width:"),
                                                            dcc.Slider(id='slider_width', min=100, max=2000, step=100, value=2000,
                                                                       marks={x: str(x) for x in range(100, 2000, 100)}),
                                                            dcc.Slider(id='slider_height', min=100, max=2000, step=100, value=1000,
                                                                       marks={x: str(x) for x in range(100, 2000, 100)}),
                                                            dcc.Graph(id='dynamic_score_graph'),
                                                            *[html.Div([html.H4(f'{metric} weight', 
                                                                                style= {'display':'inline-block',
                                                                                        'margin-right':20, 
                                                                                        'margin-top':0}),
                                                                        dcc.Input(id=f'{metric}_weight',
                                                                                  type='number',
                                                                                  value = val, 
                                                                                  style={'display':'inline-block'})],
                                                                       style={'display':'inline-block', 'width': '100%'}) 
                                                              for metric, val in mib_vals],
                                                            html.Div([html.H4('max val', 
                                                                              style= {'display':'inline-block',
                                                                                      'margin-right':20, 
                                                                                      'margin-top':0}),
                                                                      dcc.Input(id='max_val',
                                                                                type='number',
                                                                                value = 1000000, 
                                                                                style={'display':'inline-block'})], 
                                                                     style={'display':'inline-block', 
                                                                            'width': '100%'})
                                                            ]  
                                             )
                                     ])])
```

**IMAGE:**
(blue and black boxes were added manually)
[image: dash web page]

Comment: You'll get more responses if you format your code to make it easily readable, instead of a mess of whitespace that places most of the text outside the scroll box.